# How does GnuPG know the initialization vector for decryption?

Tags: encryption, pgp, gnupg, openpgp

We can decrypt an encrypted file with correct passphrase. But how can it know the correct initialization vector during decryption? Isn't it generated randomly during encryption?

Answer (score 7):

OpenPGP does not really use an initialization vector (it is defined to be all-zero). Instead, it uses a block of random data afterwards, which takes the role of the initialization vector in the OpenPGP-specific OpenPGP CFB mode.

From [RFC 4880, OpenPGP, 13.9.  OpenPGP CFB Mode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-13.9):

> OpenPGP CFB mode uses an initialization vector (IV) of all zeros, and
> prefixes the plaintext with BS+2 octets of random data, such that
> octets BS+1 and BS+2 match octets BS-1 and BS.  It does a CFB
> resynchronization after encrypting those BS+2 octets.

With other words: a construct similar to the initialization vector is included with each encrypted message, while the initialization vector is defined to be constant. So yes -- something like the initialization vector is generated during encryption, but it is stored in the encryption headers and used for decryption.

Side fact: the repetition of some octets allows early detection of wrong session keys, as it is used when trying to decrypt a message without denoted recipient (using this technique, implementations of OpenPGP can skip non-matching keys early before decrypting the whole message). On the other hand, it opens up for a rather esoteric chosen ciphertext attack as described by Mister an Zuccherato ([An Attack on CFB Mode Encryption As Used By OpenPGP](https://www.schneier.com/academic/paperfiles/paper-pgp.pdf)). One of the basic cryptographic principles is broken here: do not repeat yourself, it might open up unexpected attack vectors.

Answer (score 1):

At encryption time, the IV is stored next to the ciphertext.

Comment: Not quite -- while OpenPGP uses a similar construct stored together with the message, the IV is defined to be all-zero.

Comment: @JensErat: that depends on the mode, but it's still shipped next to the ciphertext no matter where

Comment: OpenPGP only knows one specific mode of operation: the OpenPGP CFB mode, and the IV is defined to be all-zero. Although you're right in the context that a similar construct is stored within the encryption headers.